# Get mean of values in one row in a dataframe by iterating four consecutive columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataFrame which contains the GDP values for each month:

```
[2016-1,2016-2,2016-3,2016-4,2016-5,2016-6,2016-7,2016-8,2016-9,2016-10,2016-11,2016-12]

GDP = pandas.DataFrame(
    np.random.randint(1000,1500,size=(10, 12),
    columns=[2016-1,2016-2,2016-3,2016-4,2016-5,2016-6,2016-7,2016-8,2016-9,2016-10,2016-11,2016-12])
```

I want to group the months per quarter and get the mean of the 3 months as a value for each quarter.
So

```
GDP['2000q1'] = (GDP['2016-1'] + GDP['2016-2'] + GDP['2016-3'])/3
```

Is there any was I can group by n number of columns rather by the name of the columns?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***using `resample`***

```
GDP.resample('Q', axis=1).mean()
```

[image]

---

If we first convert the columns to a period index

```
GDP.columns = GDP.columns.to_period()
```

Then the same line gives us

```
GDP.resample('Q', axis=1).mean()
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent usage of pandas!

Answer (score 0):

You can use .iloc to access columns by number
GDP.iloc[:,0:3].mean(axis=1) will return mean of first three columns
GDP.iloc[:,3:6].mean(axis=1), etc.